# How to make an UIScrollView work with Autolayout and dynamic content?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have this views hierarchy in a `xib` file:

- `UIView`
- `UIScrollView`

  - `UIView`

    - `UIView`
    - `UITableView`
- `UIButton`

Let's call `contentView` the `UIView` that is the direct child of the `UIScrollView`. I've set its top, bottom, leading and trailing constraints to pin the scroll view. Then, since I'm populating the table view at runtime and I don't know its height beforehand, I set the scroll view's `contentSize` in code:

```
[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.contentView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.size.height)];
```

But I don't make this work... what could I be missing?

Comment: Add your contrain to UIView in which child is UIScrollView. And doesn't setContentSize.

Comment: @Tanuj I've just done that, and it doesn't seem to work for me...

Comment: @AppsDev you solved your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to make this work by following the @Sana answer and also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334478/uitableview-within-uiscrollview-using-autolayout) to be able to scroll the table view content.

Thanks u all for replying.

Answer (score 2):

AppsDev, check this video out it helped me a lot doing UIScrollView via storyboard
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UnQsFlMGDsI

Also never set the scrollView's contentSize as it **has** to be determined by scrollView on its own and that's why we have AutoLayout.

I believe we should have one tag for `uiscrollview-autolayout`

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the content size manually. Instead,

1. Constrain your `contentView`'s four edges to the edges of the `scrollView`.
2. Constrain your `contentView`'s width to be equal to the `scrollView`'s width. (This will prevent the content from being wider than the `scrollView`.)
3. Constrain the `contentView`'s top and sides to the corresponding edges of the child view.
4. Constrain the `contentView's` sides and bottom to the sides and bottom of the `tableView`.
5. Now here's where it gets tricky: constrain the bottom of the child view to be equal to the top of the table view. However, unless you explicitly set a height constraint on the child view, you'll get a layout error that the height of the `scrollView`'s contents will be ambiguous. To get around this, you can set the child's placeholder height to make Interface Builder happy, but then you'll also have to set its height somewhere at runtime.

Now you should be set. The `scrollView` can now calculate the full height and width of its contents by examining the constraint hierarchy, and you don't have to set its content height manually.

Answer (score -1):

Just for example:

```
UIView *containerView               = [[UIView alloc] init];
    UIScrollView *scrollView            = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    [containerView addSubview:scrollView];

    containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints    = NO;
    NSDictionary *viewsDictionary       = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(containerView, scrollView);

    [containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[scrollView]|"
                                                                          options:kNilOptions
                                                                          metrics:nil
                                                                            views:viewsDictionary]];
    [containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[scrollView]|"
                                                                          options:kNilOptions
                                                                          metrics:nil
                                                            views:viewsDictionary]];
```

Comment: I've already set the views in IB, should I add them in code?

Comment: you added your scrollview as a subview to UIView.?

Comment: Yes, I've just embedded the scroll view in another UIView and set constraints between them in IB.

Comment: remove all the constraints from UIScrollView, only UIView constarints is enough.

Comment: checkout this example: https://github.com/jamieforrest/ScrollingButtons

Answer (score -1):

Use this code My code help you.

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
   [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.contentView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.size.height)];
}
```

Comment: You should not use setContentSize when you're using auto layout.